Matter.js with custom renderer runs twice as fast as it should
I'm trying to use JavaScript to make it so that when certain pieces of text in the document are clicked, they become physical objects and drop down to the bottom of the screen. I'm using matter.js to do this and it's only the rendering that's tripping me up.
The default renderer in matter.js doesn't allow objects to contain text, so I've made to cobble one together from what I've seen online (without really understanding it). I'm re-rendering each time I add a new object to the scene - which works perfectly fine, apart from the fact that the scene doubles in speed each time it's rendered!
I'm not a programmer, so apologies for the crazy spaghetti code. I just want this one thing to work and then I'll never have to look at the matter.js docs again. God, I can't wait.


const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const physicscanvas = document.getElementById("physicscanvas"); //canvas the scene is rendered on

const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  200, 2560, 2000, 120, {
    isStatic: true
  }
);
Matter.Composite.add(
  engine.world, [ground]
);

(function rerender() {
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
  requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
})();

//function called whenever text is clicked
function explodeMe(textid) {
  const explodedName = textid.innerHTML;

  //finds x and y of clicked name
  var x_of_physicscanvas = physicscanvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var x_of_text = textid.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var x_pos_bugged = x_of_text - x_of_physicscanvas;

  var y_of_physicscanvas = physicscanvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var y_of_text = textid.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var y_pos = y_of_text - y_of_physicscanvas;

  //hide the old text
  textid.style.visibility = "hidden";

  //create the HTML for the falling text
  const fallingContainer = document.createElement("div");
  fallingContainer.innerHTML = explodedName;
  fallingContainer.classList.add("fallingtext");
  physicscanvas.appendChild(fallingContainer);

  //find width + height
  var container_width = fallingContainer.offsetWidth;
  var container_height = fallingContainer.offsetHeight;

  //accounts for skewed width bug
  x_pos = x_pos_bugged + (container_width / 2);

  //convert html into matter.js object
  var box = {
    w: container_width,
    h: container_height,
    body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x_pos, y_pos, container_width, container_height, {
      restitution: 0.7
    }),
    elem: fallingContainer,
    render() {
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = this.body.position;
      this.elem.style.top = `${y - this.h / 2}px`;
      this.elem.style.left = `${x - this.w / 2}px`;
      this.elem.style.transform = `rotate(${this.body.angle}rad)`;
    },
  };

  //add matter.js object into canvas
  Matter.Composite.add(
    engine.world, [box.body]
  );

  //render
  (function rerender() {
    box.render();
    Matter.Engine.update(engine);
    requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
  })();

  return;
}
.fallingtext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #0f011f;
  text-align: center;
}

#physicscanvas {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 2500px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 1;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.20.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="physicscanvas">
    <div id="ground"></div>
  </div>
  <p>When <span onclick="explodeMe(this)">this</span> text is clicked, it drops! Likewise, <span onclick="explodeMe(this)">text over here</span> drops too.</p>
</div>




You have two (function rerender() { rendering loops. Remove the first.

@ggorlen I removed the first loop as you suggested, but unfortunately the issue still persists.

I see--well, each explodeMe call kicks off a new animation loop that layers on top of the others, so every text click doubles the speed. Move that loop out of explodeMe and use 1 global loop for all engine updates.

Every explodeMe call kicks off a new rendering loop, doubling the speed. Make that loop global so it's shared among all clicks:


const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const physicscanvas = document.getElementById("physicscanvas");
const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  200, 2560, 2000, 120, {
    isStatic: true
  }
);
Matter.Composite.add(
  engine.world, [ground]
);
const boxes = [];

(function rerender() {
  requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
  boxes.forEach(box => box.render());
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
})();

function explodeMe(textid) {
  const explodedName = textid.innerHTML;

  var x_of_physicscanvas = physicscanvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var x_of_text = textid.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var x_pos_bugged = x_of_text - x_of_physicscanvas;

  var y_of_physicscanvas = physicscanvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var y_of_text = textid.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var y_pos = y_of_text - y_of_physicscanvas;

  textid.style.visibility = "hidden";

  const fallingContainer = document.createElement("div");
  fallingContainer.innerHTML = explodedName;
  fallingContainer.classList.add("fallingtext");
  physicscanvas.appendChild(fallingContainer);

  var container_width = fallingContainer.offsetWidth;
  var container_height = fallingContainer.offsetHeight;

  const x_pos = x_pos_bugged + (container_width / 2);

  const box = {
    w: container_width,
    h: container_height,
    body: Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x_pos, y_pos, container_width, container_height, {
      restitution: 0.7
    }),
    elem: fallingContainer,
    render() {
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = this.body.position;
      this.elem.style.top = `${y - this.h / 2}px`;
      this.elem.style.left = `${x - this.w / 2}px`;
      this.elem.style.transform = `rotate(${this.body.angle}rad)`;
    },
  };

  Matter.Composite.add(
    engine.world, [box.body]
  );
  boxes.push(box);
}
.fallingtext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #0f011f;
  text-align: center;
}

#physicscanvas {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 2500px;
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 1;
}

span[onclick] {
  color: red;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.20.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="physicscanvas">
    <div id="ground"></div>
  </div>
  <p>When <span onclick="explodeMe(this)">this</span> text is clicked, it drops! Likewise, <span onclick="explodeMe(this)">text over here</span> drops too.</p>
</div>



I also suggest:

Using  camelCase variable names, not snake_case.
Making Box a class that encapsulates its properties and functions and shortens the explodeMe function.
Giving explodeMe a clearer name, like enablePhysics.
Using addEventListener rather than onclick (known as "unobtrusive JS").
Using const over var to avoid accidental reassignments and scoping problems.


Thank you so much! This was an incredibly helpful answer. I've had a look at the other things you suggested and implemented them too :)
